# My Ubuntu 20.04 changed to Kali 2020.02 after installing Katoolin3

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, kali, katoolin

Yesterday I installed `katoolin3` on Ubuntu 20.04. It didn't work. After that I uninstalled `katoolin3`, but it will change my Ubuntu OS to Kali GNU/linux Rolling!

Can anyone help me to get back to Ubuntu 20.04?
Also my GRUB is showing:

```
error found when loading etc/profile
```

Please help me to get out from that. Because of this, I cannot use Ubuntu properly, and my `apt-get update` shows the error:

```
404 error found
```

The command `cat /etc/os-release` shows:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Kali GNU/Linux Rolling"
NAME="Kali GNU/Linux"
ID=kali
VERSION="2020.2"
VERSION_ID="2020.2"
VERSION_CODENAME="kali-rolling"
ID_LIKE=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="https://www.kali.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.kali.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.kali.org/"
```